# TypeError: Cannot read property 'question' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typeerror

I want to display information that I get from a local .json file and use the following Javascript functions to render the information into my HTML. Console throws error for const answer even though it has already been defined. I comment it out just to see if the rest of the function works and I also get the same TypeError for question.

Below is in React, Questions.json is imported into my Play.js page:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import questions from '../../questions.json';
import isEmpty from '../../utils/is-empty';


class Play extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        questions,
        currentQuestion: {},
        nextQuestion: {},
        previousQuestion: {},
        answer:'',
        numberofQuestions: 0,
        numberOfAnsweredQuestion: 0,
        score: 0,
        correctAnswers: 0,
        wrongAnswers: 0,
        hints: 5,
        fiftyFifty: 2,
        usedFiftyFifty: false,
        time: {}
    };
}

componentDidMount () {
    const {questions, currentQuestion, nextQuestion,previousQuestion} = this.state;
    this.displayQuestions(questions,currentQuestion,nextQuestion,previousQuestion);
}

displayQuestions = (questions = this.state.questions, currentQuestion, nextQuestion, previousQuestion) => {
    let { currentQuestionIndex } = this.state;
    if (!isEmpty(this.state.questions)) {
        questions = this.state.questions;
        currentQuestion = questions[currentQuestionIndex]
        nextQuestion = questions[currentQuestionIndex + 1];
        previousQuestion = questions[currentQuestionIndex - 1];
        const answer = currentQuestion.answer;
        this.setState({
            currentQuestion,
            nextQuestion,
            previousQuestion,
            answer
        }); 

    }
};
```

This is Part of the HTML that displays the dynamic text under render.

```
<h5>{currentQuestion.question}</h5>
                <div className="options-container">
                    <p className="option">{currentQuestion.optionA}</p>
                    <p className="option">{currentQuestion.optionB}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="options-container">
                    <p className="option">{currentQuestion.optionC}</p>
                    <p className="option">{currentQuestion.optionD}</p>
                </div>
```

Comment: Does it work if you change `displayQuestions` from `(questions = this.state.questions, etc)` to `(questions = questions, etc)` ?

Comment: Changed displayQuestions to (myquestions = questions, etc) and that seems to solve the issue of getting rid of any existing errors, now I can see static content. Console.log(currentQuestions) is still undef and functions logic still doesn't render currentQuestion.

Answer (score 0):

In your `displayQuestions(questions=questions,..)` function, dont use `questions`. Use a different variable name, like `(awesome=questions)`.

Comment: Changed displayQuestions to (myquestions = questions, etc) and that seems to solve the issue of getting rid of any existing errors, now I can see static content. Console.log(currentQuestions) is still undef and functions logic still doesn't render currentQuestion.